# What is the origin of the Blue Falcon?

Tags: hanna-barbera, dynomutt-dog-wonder

Is there a proper, established backstory for the cartoon hero the Blue Falcon? Granted he's supposed to be a bit of a Batman spoof hero, but he seems to have grown beyond that.

What's his background, his training and how did he come to be? Or are we to just believe that Radley Crowne just "Decided" to be a superhero one day and mail ordered a robotic dog?

And where **did** Dynomutt come from, anyway?

Comment: https://youtu.be/Mxjwl4vgCak might have info. Can't watch it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original show had no origin for the duo, they just were there and did their thing.

In 2012 however, in the *Scooby-Doo! Mystery Incorporated* episode "Heart of Evil", an origin of a sort was added for Dynomutt.

In the episode Blue Falcon was an ordinary security guard called  Radley Crowne who had an interest in birds, and a dog partner called Reggie. While they were working for Professor Quest, the father of [Jonny Quest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jonny_Quest), guarding his lab  it was attacked by a robot-dragon sent by the super villain Dr Zin. Reggie tried to attack the robot but was outmatched and crushed. Professor Quest managed to drive away the robot but Radley was devastated by his dog's death. As a way of thanks, Dr Quest took Reggie to his lab and rebuilt him as an android, calling him Dynomutt.

Since *Scooby-Doo! Mystery Incorporated* is a relaunch of the original *Scooby-Doo* series, and the original Blue Falcon and Dynomutt teamed up several times with the Scooby gang, we can assume this origin is a reboot too and may not be what was considered the original one, if one ever existed. But so far it seems to be all we have.